# Capybara Minitest `has_field?` works, but `assert_field` gives error "unused parameters passed to Capybara::Queries::SelectorQuery"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capybara, minitest

In my page, I have a link like this:

```html
<input value="" data-autofocus="true" class="form-control" 
       type="text" name="user[login]" id="user_login" />
```

Using Capybara with Minitest, driver :rack_test, the following selector finds the input, but the parallel assertion gets an error [edited to include the trace]:

```rb
(ruby) has_field?("user_login")
true
(ruby) assert_field("user_login")
eval error: Unused parameters passed to Capybara::Queries::SelectorQuery : [:field, "user_login"]
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.4/gems/capybara-3.37.1/lib/capybara/queries/selector_query.rb:52:in `initialize'
  /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.4/gems/capybara-3.37.1/lib/capybara/node/matchers.rb:842:in `new'
  /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.4/gems/capybara-3.37.1/lib/capybara/node/matchers.rb:842:in `_verify_selector_result'
  /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.4/gems/capybara-3.37.1/lib/capybara/node/matchers.rb:110:in `assert_selector'
  /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.4/gems/capybara-3.37.1/lib/capybara/session.rb:771:in `assert_selector'
  /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.4/gems/capybara-3.37.1/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:52:in `call'
  /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.4/gems/capybara-3.37.1/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:52:in `assert_selector'
  /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.4/gems/capybara-3.37.1/lib/capybara/minitest.rb:288:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Assertions>'
  (rdbg)//vagrant/mo/test/integration/capybara_student_test.rb:1:in `block in test_creating_drafts'
nil
```

The [rubydocs for `Capybara::Minitest::Assertions#assert_field`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/capybara/Capybara%2FMinitest%2FAssertions:assert_field) say that the method is built straight off [`Node::Matchers#has_field?`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/capybara/Capybara/Node/Matchers#has_field%3F-instance_method). I wonder why it isn't working?

EDIT: Belatedly realizing this is probably relevant... I'm including Capybara::Minitest::Assertions in the tests, and using Sean P. Doyle's gem [ActionDispatch::Testing::Integration::Capybara](https://github.com/thoughtbot/action_dispatch-testing-integration-capybara) to use Capybara in integration tests.

Comment: It's possible there's a bug in Capybara - what version are you using?

Comment: Hi @ThomasWalpole - i'm using Capybara 3.36.0 with Rails 6.1.6. Further note above.

Comment: I noticed that Capybara's spec for `assert_field` (https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/b8705059b142930e97fcbd8f34b9409755570c44/spec/minitest_spec.rb) doesn't seem to exercise method options beyond the locator. If there is a bug, it might have sneaked by the tests.

Comment: I tried with the fields you are using and it works fine.  I'm guessing this is an interaction with the ActionDispatch::Testing::Integration::Capybara  gem... Do you have a full stack trace of the error?  If I had to guess I'd say that gem is overwriting asset_field and screwing with the parameters

Comment: You might also want to update to capybara 3.37.1 just so. you're running latest

Comment: Updated the issue description — it doesn't have anything to do with hidden fields. Other assertions work, just not "assert_field"

Comment: There shouldn't be any reference to dsl.rb in that call stack, so something is included in your environment in the wrong order.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the eagle eye of @ThomasWalpole for pointing the way — I didn't know it mattered so much where `require`s and `include`s are located in the ancestry of a class.

First of all, the author of the experimental [gem](https://github.com/thoughtbot/action_dispatch-testing-integration-capybara) i was using informed me that my manual includes of the Capybara classes were redundant; they are already included by the gem. I removed the gem to isolate the problem, which was present already had before adding the gem.

The core of it was, having `require capybara/rails`, `require capybara/minitest` and `include Capybara::DSL` in my `test_helper.rb`, but `include Capybara::Minitest::Assertions` in my separate `CapybaraIntegrationTestCase.rb` seems to have put the call stack out of order. Moving all Capybara requires and includes to the `CapybaraIntegrationTestCase` cleared this up.